# Android Parse Crash

Tags: android, crash, parse-platform

I am trying to add Parse to my Android App. I first started by dragging the Parse files into my Android Studio project. Next I added this to my application onCreate:

```
Parse.initialize(this, myParseAppID, myParseClientID");
```

The app ID and client ID are correct but the app still crashes.

I am not getting any logs:

[image]

Also I **DID** add this to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like this

```
 Parse.initialize(Splash.this, "","");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(Splash.this, ParsePush.class);
```

Comment: I get error saying `Gradle: cannot find symbol class Splash`

Comment: use ur current activity name.

Comment: try to use GCM. Its far better than parse.

Comment: Parse is based on GCM

Answer (score 0):

How did you add the dependency on Android studio? Try adding the parse jar file directly to your libs folder. It works for me.